# Problema con actualizar ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, alertdialog

solicito ayuda he buscado pero no he encontrado que es lo que estoy haciendo mal para que no me actualize el listview, despues de haber modificado la tabla con un Alertdialog les agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

```
public class Pedidos extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private List<Productos> productosList = new ArrayList<Productos>();
private SQLiteDatabase db;
ListView listViewP;
TextView textTotal, prodcod, prodnombre, prodstock, prodprecio, totlin;
EditText editcantidad;

private DBHelper helper;
Spinner spinnerfamilia;
private GruposAdapter gruposAdapter;
private ProductosAdapter productosAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pedido);

    listViewP = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewP);
    spinnerfamilia = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    textTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView28);

    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    gruposAdapter = new GruposAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, helper.recuperarGrupos());
    gruposAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerfamilia.setAdapter(gruposAdapter);
    spinnerfamilia.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    productosList = helper.recuperarProductos();
    productosAdapter = new ProductosAdapter(this,productosList);

    listViewP.setAdapter(productosAdapter);
    productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listViewP.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Productos productos = productosAdapter.getItem(i);

            final String codProd;
            final Integer precio;

            codProd = productos.getCodigo();
            precio = productos.getPrecioNeto();

            final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Pedidos.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input_box, null);

            prodcod = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
            prodnombre = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
            prodstock = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView23);
            prodprecio = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView24);
            editcantidad = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText11);
            totlin = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);

            prodcod.setText(codProd);
            prodnombre.setText(productos.getDescripcion());
            prodstock.setText(String.valueOf(productos.getStock()));
            prodprecio.setText("Precio Neto $" + String.valueOf(precio));
            editcantidad.setText(String.valueOf(productos.getCantidad()));

            editcantidad.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    if(editcantidad.getText().length()>=1) {
                         int precioU =  Math.round(precio*(1+19/100));
                         int total = Integer.valueOf(editcantidad.getText().toString()) * precioU;
                         totlin.setText(String.valueOf(total));

                    }
                }
            });


            mBuilder.setView(mView)
            .setTitle("Cantidad")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    helper.actualizarCantProd(codProd, Integer.valueOf(editcantidad.getText().toString()), Integer.valueOf(totlin.getText().toString()));
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog =   mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    });

    textTotal.setText("Total $" + helper.montoPedido());
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Grupos grupos = gruposAdapter.getItem(i);
    productosAdapter.getFilter().filter(Long.toString(grupos.getCodGrup()), new Filter.FilterListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFilterComplete(int i) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```

Comment: explica mejor tu problema, dejas solo el codigo

Comment: Has hecho algo de código para actualizar la lista? Veo que actualizas el producto pero en ningún momento actualizas el listado.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia aquí

```
.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            helper.actualizarCantProd(codProd, Integer.valueOf(editcantidad.getText().toString()), Integer.valueOf(totlin.getText().toString()));
     }
});
```

a esto

```
.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            helper.actualizarCantProd(codProd, Integer.valueOf(editcantidad.getText().toString()), Integer.valueOf(totlin.getText().toString()));
            productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     }
});
```

Cada vez que modifiques la entrada de datos, debes notificar al adapter que la información ha cambiado.

Comment: Disculpen por haberme explicado poco, tengo un listview que muestra listado de productos, que los filtra por Familia y quiero poder ingresar la cantidad solicitada, lo cual para ingresar llamo a un AlertDialog, ya que tambien hice otro activity y no me funciono tampoco la actualizacion de la cantidad solicitada.